# Find and update row in Pandas DataFrame with non-unique index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with a non-unique index, and I need to update one of the rows.  I am able to update the row if I can index it numerically, as below:

```
array = np.random.randint(1, 10, (3, 3))
df = pd.DataFrame(array, index=['one', 'one', 'two'], columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])

# df looks like this:
#        col1   col2    col3
#one        2       3       6
#one        3       1       5
#two        4       5       2


new_data = pd.Series({'col1': 'new', 'col2': 'new', 'col3': 'new'})
df.iloc[0] = new_data
```

But what if I don't know the row number?  Let's say I just want to set the first row with an index of 'one'.  So, I want to find the slice using `.loc` and then assign my new value to the first row.

```
new_data = pd.Series({'col1': 'new', 'col2': 'new', 'col3': 'new'})
df.loc['one'][0] = new_data
```

However, this is assignment using chained indexing, which is not so good. Is there a different way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it with `df.iloc[(df.index == 'one').argmax()]`.

So your assignment would look like:

```
df.iloc[(df.index == 'one').argmax()] = new_data
```

Comment: This does indeed do what I asked for, but it isn't very generalizable.  If I want to get the _last_ row with an index of 'one' instead of the first row, I can't just use `argmin()`.  Is there not a more broad way of doing this?

Comment: @JJones The problem is you need to specify a rule for selecting within the group of indices that match.  I challenge you to specify what it is that you'd like generalized?  Do you want a general way to grab the nth of a particular match?  If so, I'd ask another question.  This question did ask for the first 'one'.